# Updating EF5 to EF6 Error

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework

I've updated my app EF from 5 to latest release EF6, since I'm using CF approach, I think all required changes in the imports has been automatically changed during the update .. fine.

But other parts has been spoiled like, (1) when I run Asp.net Configuration from VS12 it raises this error

> [Method not found: 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.IObjectContextAdapter.get_ObjectContext()'.]

(2) I'm using the login wizard form which in the VS12, this one also not working anymore.

Any idea what I need to change to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this can help : 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn469466

Namespace changes :

System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext => System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext

Comment: I've done that before I post the this question, all my forms working fine & retrieving data from mssql db, accept one page which created by vs2012 when created the application manage.aspx
Also I'm not able to find any page using the old System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext to replace it!

Comment: May be this is because the conflict in the assemblies coz I'm getting more errors when I build the app as follow:
Consider app.config remapping of assembly "EntityFramework, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" from Version "5.0.0.0" [] to Version "6.1.0.0" [..\EMS_v0.1_With_EF6\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.0-alpha1-21017\lib\net45\EntityFramework.dll] to solve conflict and get rid of warning.